# How Do I Make the tmux Rename Window Prompt Empty by Default?

Tags: tmux

In tmux, pressing **`prefix + ,`** prompts you to rename the current window:

[image]

The **`(rename-window)`** prompt is automatically populated with the current window name -- in this case, **`zsh`**.

I would rather the the **`(rename-window)`** prompt **not** be pre-populated with the current window name because more times than not, I end up deleting the current window name before typing the new one.

Is there a tmux option or plugin that can make the **`(rename-window)`** prompt empty by default?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The tmux command for **`prefix + ,`** can be seen in the list of command, which is displayed when you press **`prefix + ?`**

Default should look like this:

`bind-key          , command-prompt -I #W "rename-window '%%'"`

Just cut off the `-I #W` part from there to get the empty value as default suggestion when renaming.

That is, put this line in your tmux.conf:

`bind-key          , command-prompt "rename-window '%%'"`

and reload the tmux config/ restart the tmux